# Why is my parallelized for loop giving a different output?

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, pthreads, 2d

I declare my threads like this:

```
for (thread_num = 0; thread_num < NUM_THREADS; thread_num++) //for each thread do
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread_num], NULL, gemver_default, (void*)thread_num); //create and run the thread. The thread will run the gemver_default. The thread_num will be passed as input to the gemver_default().


    for (thread_num = 0; thread_num < NUM_THREADS; thread_num++) //for each thread do
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread_num], NULL); //wait for the thread to finish
```

Then my pthread loop:

```
unsigned short int gemver_default(void * thread_num) {
    long int my_thread_num = (long int)thread_num; //store the input of the function to my_thread_num
    

    int local = P / NUM_THREADS; //the number of array elements that each thread must compute their sqrt
    
    int starting_element = my_thread_num * local; //first array element to be computed by this thread
    int ending_element = starting_element + local - 1; //last array element to be computed by this thread
    
    for (i = starting_element; i < ending_element; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < local; j++)
                    A2[i][j] += u1[i] * v1[j] + u2[i] * v2[j];
    

}
```

Then my original loop:

```
unsigned short int gemver_default() {

    //this is the loop to parallelize
    for (int i = 0; i < P; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
            A2[i][j] += u1[i] * v1[j] + u2[i] * v2[j];

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand why the outputs are different?

I have created the threads, referenced the function that I want to work on, and implemented this into my old loop.

Comment: Have you initialized _all_ of your variables?  I would not ask, but since you have not posted a [mcve], I had to.  ( eg how was `A2` created, i.e. as `int **A2 = NULL;, then `malloc'd` some memory, or `intA2[X][Y];`.  Either of these are examples of uninitialized variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently see two small issues in your code:

1.
You are setting `ending_element = starting_element + local - 1`,
but then in the loop the condition is `i < ending_element`.

You should change it so either `ending_element = starting_element + local`,
or change the ondition in the loop to `i <= ending_element`.

2.
If P is divisible by `NUM_THREADS` without remainder, using `P / NUM_THREADS` will work fine, but if not, then your threads will not cover all the indexes from 0 to P. For example, if `P = 14` and `NUM_THREADS = 5`, then `P / NUM_THREADS = 2`, and your threads will only handle indexes 0 through 9, ignoring indexes 10 through 13.

Solution to this problem: You can set `local = P / NUM_THREADS + 1`,
and change the condition in the loop from `i < ending_element` to `(i < ending_element) && (i < P)`.